# If Entity framework model include indexes in model when generating model from database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

When generated model (edmx) from database with entity framework, all Key and constraint will be included in model.

So want to know if index also include in model? For example, if I change a unique index(not for primary key) on database, does it impact edmx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. An index is a pure database helper construct. EF doesn't care about it. It also doesn't care (yet) about the uniqueness of an index (other than the PK index) because EF doesn't yet support unique key constraints.